# matplotlib plot values from loop as individual lines on the same plot, assign legend based on loop variable

Tags: python, for-loop, matplotlib, legend

I have a loop that does some calculations to get the values that populate `pcorr_list` and then plots this data as a line on an existing plot.

```
    for event in event_name_list:
        event_string = str(event)
        event_name = 'AGW_' + str(event_string)

        ###some code to calculate pcorr1 : pcorr5

        pcorr_list = [pcorr1, pcorr2, pcorr3, pcorr4, pcorr5]
        plt.plot(turbine_list_pcorr, pcorr_list,'-o', label = event_name)
plt.legend(event_name, loc = 'best')
plt.show()
```

I want a legend for the plot show `event_name` for the pcorr data for the corresponding `event` in the loop.

At the moment the legend is the last event in the loop split into individual characters and doesn't relate to the lines in the plot.

`plt.plot(turbine_list_pcorr, pcorr_list,'-o', label = str(event_name))` returns the same result.

[image]

Comment: can you remove `event_name` from the call to legend? i.e. `plt.legend(loc = 'best')`

Comment: Yep, that's it. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As commented by @Diziet Asahi

```
    for event in event_name_list:
        event_string = str(event)
        event_name = 'AGW_' + str(event_string)

        ###some code to calculate pcorr1 : pcorr5

        pcorr_list = [pcorr1, pcorr2, pcorr3, pcorr4, pcorr5]
        plt.plot(turbine_list_pcorr, pcorr_list,'-o', label = event_name)
plt.legend(loc = 'best')
plt.show()
```